# "Delete" link from Controller does not go to "Delete" page

Tags: linq, webforms, repository, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is homework, an ASP.NET MVC and Web forms Web application using a repository (with data hard coded without a database) to rate doctors.  The user should be able to edit and delete entries, but the "Delete" link on the Controller does not go to the "Delete" page. However, when I hover over the "Delete" link, the URI is:  DoctorApplication/Delete?DoctorPicture=Images/0.cropped.jpg.  I'm using string DoctorPicture instead of int ID throughout the app, and I'm thinking the path Images/0.cropped instead of 0.cropped without the Images directory is why my Delete view isn't showing, but in my TestDoctorRepository, I have DoctorPicture = "Images/0cropped.jpg" so that the image can display on the page.  Why isn't the "Delete" view showing?

```
public TestDoctorRepository()
        {
            doctors = new List<Doctor> {
                new Doctor { DoctorPicture = "Images/0cropped.jpg", DoctorName = "Michael Shores", DoctorSpecialty = "Opthamology", times = 0, rating = 0, rated = true, avg=0, fave = true },
            // more code

            };
        }

public void Remove(string DoctorPicture)
        {
            var doctor = from d in doctors where d.DoctorPicture == DoctorPicture select d;
            doctors.Remove(doctor.FirstOrDefault());
        }
```

From DoctorApplicationController:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string DoctorPicture)
        {
            repo.Remove(DoctorPicture);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //private ActionResult View(Func<List<Doctor>> func)
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}

        //
        // POST: /DoctorApplication/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(string DoctorPicture, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                repo.Remove(DoctorPicture);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `Delete` function in the controller in redirecting you to the Index action of the page instead of to a dedicated Delete view. It's doing the exact same thing as your POST `Delete` method, minus the try-catch block. You should change that to point to your delete view name.

The URL on an MVC page points to which action is will run when that link is clicked. It's running the correct action (your `Delete` call), but then sees that it should then go to the Index action on your Controller (which would then NOT go to your delete page). What you are seeing is correct: It is going to `Delete`, but `Delete` is redirecting to the Index.

Comment: I changed the Delete methods to:
public ActionResult Delete(string DoctorPicture)
        {
            repo.Remove(DoctorPicture);
            return RedirectToAction("Delete");
        }
and
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(string DoctorPicture, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                repo.Remove(DoctorPicture);
                return RedirectToAction("Delete");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
but when I ran it...

Comment: an error said, "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: That's because you can't redirect it to itself. You're using the wrong return statement. `RedirectToAction` is essentially the same as calling a specific method in the controller. Therefore, your `Delete` method having `RedirectToAction("Delete")` will never end because it will keep on calling itself. You need to have something like `return View("Delete");`

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  
Now on the delete page, to make the delete button work, should I change this?  
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>

Comment: I think you would. I would recommend having that be a different question, though. Your main question here was for getting the link to work, which it now does.